# XSLT Group by unique parameter

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I am trying to convert  the Input xml value to Output xml using xslt based on for-each-group logic of RAPID_ID

**Input.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Output>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <CustomerName>KUMAR</CustomerName>
        <BranchName>HARBOUR</BranchName>
        <SchemeName>GOLD</SchemeName>
        <MobileNumber>123456789</MobileNumber>
        <CustomerType>PRIMARY</CustomerType>
        <DedupeFound>NO</DedupeFound>
    </Output>
    <Output>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <CustomerName>SEAN</CustomerName>
        <BranchName>HARBOUR</BranchName>
        <SchemeName>GOLD</SchemeName>
        <MobileNumber>123456789</MobileNumber>
        <CustomerType>SECONDARY</CustomerType>
        <DedupeFound>YES</DedupeFound>
    </Output>
    <Output>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <CustomerName>MARK</CustomerName>
        <BranchName>CANTONMENT</BranchName>
        <SchemeName>DIAMOND</SchemeName>
        <MobileNumber>123456789</MobileNumber>
        <CustomerType>PRIMARY</CustomerType>
        <DedupeFound>NO</DedupeFound>
    </Output>
    <Output>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <CustomerName>STEVE</CustomerName>
        <BranchName>CANTONMENT</BranchName>
        <SchemeName>DIAMOND</SchemeName>
        <MobileNumber>123456789</MobileNumber>
        <CustomerType>SECONDARY</CustomerType>
        <DedupeFound>YES</DedupeFound>
    </Output>
</Response>
```

My Expected output is

**Output.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response>
    <Output>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <CustomerName>KUMAR</CustomerName>
        <BranchName>HARBOUR</BranchName>
        <SchemeName>GOLD</SchemeName>
        <MobileNumber>123456789</MobileNumber>
        <DedupeDetails>
            <CustomerType>PRIMARY</CustomerType>
            <CustomerName>KUMAR</CustomerName>
            <DedupeFound>NO</DedupeFound>
        </DedupeDetails>
        <DedupeDetails>
            <CustomerType>SECONDARY</CustomerType>
            <CustomerName>SEAN</CustomerName>
            <DedupeFound>YES</DedupeFound>
        </DedupeDetails>
    </Output>
    <Output>
        <ID>5678</ID>
        <CustomerName>MARK</CustomerName>
        <BranchName>CANTONMENT</BranchName>
        <SchemeName>DIAMOND</SchemeName>
        <MobileNumber>123456789</MobileNumber>
        <DedupeDetails>
            <CustomerType>PRIMARY</CustomerType>
            <CustomerName>MARK</CustomerName>
            <DedupeFound>NO</DedupeFound>
        </DedupeDetails>
        <DedupeDetails>
            <CustomerType>SECONDARY</CustomerType>
            <CustomerName>STEVE</CustomerName>
            <DedupeFound>YES</DedupeFound>
        </DedupeDetails>
    </Output>
</Response>
```

I started with something like this but not able to proceed further.
I am trying to group ID parameters first, Inside that It start with primary customer Details.
After Primary customer Details I have to iterate each customer ( Both Primary & secondary Here )

Any Suggestions / Corrections to make this achievable.

**My XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Response>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="/Response/Output" group-by="ID">
      <xsl:sort select="ID"/>


    </xsl:for-each-group>
            
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is no `RAPID_ID` in your XML sample, so the XSLT doesn't make any sense for the input sample you have shown.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Apologies. I have corrected the xslt. I pasted different version of xslt initially.

Comment: Well. `<xsl:for-each-group select="/Response/Output" group-by="ID">` looks fine, but if you don't create any content there will be none, so at least `<xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy>` will form the content of the `for-each-group`, to create one output for each group. Then populate with the elements you need and process the different items in the group based on `current-group()` if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="op" match="Output" use="ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/Response">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Output[CustomerType='PRIMARY']">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="ID|CustomerName|BranchName|SchemeName"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('op', ID)">
                    <DedupeDetails>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="CustomerType|CustomerName|DedupeFound"/>
                    </DedupeDetails>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this assumes that each group has exactly one PRIMARY customer and zero or more SECONDARY customers. If the input always has one PRIMARY customer followed by one SECONDARY customer, as in your example, then this could be even simpler.

Comment: Hi Michel. I will try with your approach & let you know. Your assumption is right. The input has one primary and multiple secondary